# Get a sub array using array of indexes in one step

Tags: c#, arrays, indexing

In C#, given an array of integers that represents indexes of an array of items, is there a way to get a sub-array of the array of items that correspond to indexes in one step?

```
int[] indexesArray = {0,2,4,1};
string[] itemsArray = {"hi", "ciao", "yo"," hey","hello"};

string[] result = builtinMagic(itemsArray, indexesArray);
```

Comment: This is called *slicing*

Comment: Use a 2D/ multidimensional array?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply `Select` the index from the `indexesArray` and then get the item at that specific index:

```
string[] result = indexesArray.Select(idx => itemsArray[idx]).ToArray();
```

Comment: You are too fast for me :)

Comment: I have that a lot ;)